# Remove All Taxonomies from Post On Update

Tags: plugin-development, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I've got a custom post type set up with custom taxonomies. When a user updates a post I need a way to check to see if there are any `location` taxonomies applied and if so then remove them.

I've managed to sort the updating part out. So when post is saved it adds the correct `Location` taxonomy. I'm using two custom taxonomies on the custom post type too. `Locations` and `Industry`. So I need to only check the `Location` taxonomy and remove any that have been set for that specific post while leaving `Industry` alone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've checked the WP docs site but found I was getting in a muddle with `terms`, `taxonomy` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be handled with [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/) call on [`save_post_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) action. Using the post type specific action you'll only target your cpt.

The action provides `bool $update` parameter, which can be used to check, if the action is fired for a new post or on update.

Passing an empty `$terms` value to the function clears any existing terms of the set taxonomy, which saves you the effort of first checking, if any terms exist.

```
// update action to match your custom post type
add_action( 'save_post_{$post_type}', 'my_clear_post_locations_on_update', 10, 3 );
function my_clear_post_locations_on_update(int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update) {
  // only affect updates, not new post saves
  if ( ! $update ) {
    return;
  }
  // nuke taxonomy terms from the post
  // store return value in a variable for checking the result, if interested
  wp_set_object_terms(
    $post_ID, // object ID
    array(), // terms
    'location', // taxonomy
    false // append
  );
}
```

*P.S. Replace the empty array with a term slug, single term ID, or array of either term slugs or IDs, if you want to force term/s on the post.*

Comment: Awesome thank you! I just couldn't get my head around it at all. You've made it look really easy!